# Convolution integral with fraction expansion

Tags: fourier-transform, convolution, dirichlet-convolution

I have to solve this convolution integral $$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\frac{1}{T_1} + i2\pi \tau } + \frac{1}{\frac{1}{T_2} + i2\pi (f- \tau) } d \tau  $$ but I have a lot of problems with partial fraction expansions (my book tells to use this method ). First of all I can write it like this $$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{A}{\frac{1}{T_1} + i2\pi \tau } + \frac{B}{\frac{1}{T_2} + i2\pi (f- \tau) } d\tau $$ and after I found least common denominator  $$  A{\frac{1}{T_2} + i2\pi (f- \tau) } + B{\frac{1}{T_1} + i2\pi \tau }=1 $$ . I wrote 1 because in the first numerator i hadn’t any other components except for 1.  Now I solved and I obtained $$ \tau ( - Ai2 \pi + Bi2 \pi ) + Ai2 \pi f + \frac{A}{T_2} + \frac{B}{T_1} - 1 = 0 $$ at this point I wrote that all the tau component is 0 , because the original numerator was 1. I don’t know if there’s something right however now I’m completely blocked :/

Comment: Just like the last time you asked this question, you cannot partial fraction something that has already been partial fractioned. $A=B=1$

Comment: The expression as is already has an easy antiderivative. Try integrating at this stage and see how to take the limits.

Comment: I repost the question ( after cancel the previous post ) because I didn’t know how to change the name post. And I’m sorry but for me this is not so easy. My book obtained $$ A = B =[ {T_1^{-1} + T_2^{-1}+ j2 f \pi  }]^{-1}$$  and I don’t know why.

Comment: It's not that this is easy, its just that as you have written it, *there is nothing to do*. You may want to recheck to see if you have typed it up incorrectly. Do you see why $\frac{A}{s}+\frac{B}{t} = \frac{1}{s} + \frac{1}{t} \implies A = B =1$ ? This is not a math issue, just a logic one.

Comment: From my last I obtained $$ \tau ( - Ai2 \pi + Bi2 \pi ) + Ai2 \pi f + \frac{A}{T_2} + \frac{B}{T_1} - 1 = 0 $$. I see that A=B=1 when I see you last post but this is not what I obtained  in mine. Solving mine I obtained $$ Ai2 \pi f + \frac{A}{T_2} + \frac{B}{T_1} - 1 = 0 $$ if the tau component is 0

Comment: You didn't answer my question, nor did you address the issue that your first line and second line *are exactly the same thing*. This is not meant to be yelling, I just need you to answer the points I'm emphasizing because you are talking about a completely different thing which doesn't logically follow from what you have written in your post.

Comment: I have the solution of this exercise but I sincerely don‘t understand why my question is so illogical. I didn’t know how to solve this convolution integral so I follow the steps of the solution, using fraction expansion, but probably I have a big gap on this method  or I have No logic at the moment because I don’t understand